# Create a git repository with gitolite and push an existing local repository to it

Tags: git, gitolite

I have a local new-repo folder with a git in it that I want to publish in gitolite on my server.

On my server I created a new git repository `new-repo` in the admin as root with this section:

```
[group developers]
writable = old-repo new-repo
members = me@myhost
```

and pused it, but I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gitosis-serve", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gitosis==0.2', 'console_scripts', 'gitosis-serve')()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gitosis/app.py", line 24, in run
    return app.main()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gitosis/app.py", line 38, in main
    self.handle_args(parser, cfg, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gitosis/serve.py", line 196, in handle_args
    command=cmd,
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gitosis/serve.py", line 154, in serve
    config=cfg,
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gitosis/gitdaemon.py", line 79, in set_export_ok
    assert ext == '.git'
AssertionError
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

there isn't added any new repo in my gitolite folder and I cannot push to it.

What am I doing wrong?

*(I use gitosis still, so maybe is gitosis so outdated by now, that it doesn't work anymore like gitolite?)*

Comment: Did you mean you modified a gitolite-admin repo conf file on your server?

Comment: yes. I checked out the admin repo, edited the file `gitosis.conf` and puhed that.

Comment: Maybe It is not allowed to add two repos in one line? `old-repo new-repo`

Comment: No it is allowed to have two in one line and python 2.7 was okk too. I added an answer with my solution

Comment: You are switching back and forth between gitosis and gitolite. It looks like you use gitosis. Is that right? Gitolite is an entirely different piece of software.

Comment: not so different ;) everything works the same. And I did solve it already, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did everything correct.

The problem was visible due to the line:

```
assert ext == '.git'
```

A few days ago I diabled a repo by renaming it int `some_repo.git_old`

so there was a repo in my folder that didn't end with `.git`

I renamed it

```
mv some_repo.git_old some_repo_old.git
```

and now those errormessages are gone.

Also I had to add `-u origin master` to my first push message:

```
git remote add origin git@myserver.de:new-repo.git
git push -u origin master
```